# Missing number, treated as zero using BibTeX in IOP template

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using the IOP template from [here](http://authors.iop.org/atom/help.nsf/0/B042B0AF79C815B88025702000409514?OpenDocument) and the `iopart-num` package.

Here is `iopdebug.bib`:

```
@article{debugitem,
  title = {This is the title},
  author = {Surname, N and Lastname, F},
  journal = {Journ},
  volume = {123},
  number = {1},
  pages = {1--2},
  year = {2000},
  publisher = {Debugging}
}
```

and this is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,A4,final]{iopart}
\usepackage{iopams}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{citesort}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

Attempt to cite~\cite{debugitem}

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\bibliography{iopdebug.bib}

\end{document}
```

I run `pdfLaTeX` then `BibTeX` then `pdfLaTeX` and everything is normal up till here (the reference list displays properly). But when I run `pdfLaTeX` the third time, I get:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.10 Attempt to cite~\cite{debugitem}
```

However, if `\cite{debugitem}` is omitted then there is no error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last there are two errors in your code.

The first is that you used command `\bibliography` with the file extention `.bib`.  Just delete the extention (In my MWE I used package `filecontents` to have bib file and tex code together in one compilable MWE. Thats the reason I changed the file neame to `\jobname.bib`).

The second problem is package `citesort`.  It seems to be very old (your used class too) and causes the error you got.  Just delete it or comment is (as I did in my MWE). Please see that in your code `hyperref` should be the last package to be called.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{debugitem,
  title   = {This is the title},
  author  = {Surname, N and Lastname, F},
  journal = {Journ},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1--2},
  year    = {2000},
  publisher = {Debugging},
}
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass[12pt,A4,final]{iopart}

%\usepackage{citesort} % <================================ causes error!
\usepackage{iopams}

\usepackage[%
  breaklinks=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue
]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

Attempt to cite~\cite{debugitem}.

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\bibliography{\jobname}% \jobname.bib <=================================

\end{document}
```

and the reult:

[image: result of mwe above]